# Find nesting and sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, recursion

**Situation:**
I have 'pages' that have links to other pages, these pages will be stored in the database so to store 1 I would need to store its linked pages first (for the foreign key).
So what I need to do is find all the pages linked from the selected page up until the root.

**Example:**
A - links to - B & C & D
B - links to - C & F
C - links to - E & F
D - links to - B & C
E - links to - F
F - links to - No links

The correct nesting order in this example would be:
F - E - C - B - D - A

*Note usually I have closer to 30 pages with links all over the place*

**Problem:**
I already have code for this which works, but getting the links from each page takes a while (average of 800ms) so I would like to check the links for the pages as little as possible.

**Code example: (not production code)**

```
static class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<int, int[]> Dict = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
    private static int hitcount = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Example data
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Dict.Add( 1, new int[]{2, 3, 4});
        Dict.Add(2, new int[] {3, 6 });
        Dict.Add(3, new int[] { 5, 6 });
        Dict.Add(4, new int[] { 2, 3 });
        Dict.Add(5, new int[] { 6 });
        Dict.Add(6, new int[] {});

        var links = GetAllLinks( 1 );
        foreach ( var link in links )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(link.ToString());
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("MS:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " - " + hitcount);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    private static List<int> GetLinksFromKey(int key)
    {
        //This usually takes avg 800ms so sleep here
        //This is the BottleNeck, the more often its called longer it will take
        Thread.Sleep( 800 );
        hitcount++;
        return Dict[key].ToList();
    }

    private static List<int> GetAllLinks(int key)
    {
        var allPages = new List<int>();
        var pages = new List<int>();
        pages.Add(key);
        while (true)
        {
            var i = 0;
            var newP = new List<int>();
            newP.AddRange(pages);
            foreach (var page in pages.Distinct())
            {
                if (allPages.Contains(page))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                newP.AddRange(GetLinksFromKey(page));
                i++;
                allPages.Add(page);
            }
            pages = new List<int>(newP);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return SortLinks(new List<int>(allPages.Distinct()));
    }

    private static List<int> SortLinks(List<int> pagesToSort)
    {
        var sortedPages = new List<int>();
        var hasReference = new List<int>();
        while (sortedPages.Count != pagesToSort.Count)
        {
            foreach (var page in pagesToSort)
            {
                if (sortedPages.Contains(page))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var links = GetLinksFromKey(page);
                if (new List<int>(links.Distinct()).RemoveListFromList(sortedPages).Count == 0)
                {
                    sortedPages.Add(page);
                }
                else
                {
                    hasReference.Add(page);
                }
                if (hasReference.Distinct().Count() == pagesToSort.Distinct().Count())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There are circular references, can't find the root.");
                    return sortedPages;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedPages;
    }
    private static List<int> RemoveListFromList(this List<int> mainList, List<int> removeList)
    {
        foreach (var item in removeList)
        {
            if (mainList.Contains(item))
            {
                mainList.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        return mainList;
    }
}
```

I made this code as an example for my nesting situation, I made it so it works with a dictionary instead of a page. Using the dictionary for this is very fast but I know in which method the bottleneck is so if anyone has a solution where I use it less that would be great.

**Question:**
Is there anyway to make this more efficient? As I feel I'm doing it wrong.
If there isn't a faster way to do this, I would also appreciate to hear.

**If you can make hitcount < 20 and have the same output as me (6 - 5 - 3 - 2 - 4 - 1) you have already improved it**

Comment: There is a way to make it O(N) - process the pages in any order. Every time you find a link to a page that doesn't exist, create a placeholder entry in the database. Then, when you finally get to the linked page, just update the placeholder.

Comment: @RB Why can't it be O(N)? With recursion it seems to be simple...

Comment: I need to find the nesting order etc. before I store it because there may be circular references which we do not allow :)

Comment: @xanatos Yep, sorry, you're right. My way is more memory efficient, but not necessarily more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recursion it should be:

```
public static Dictionary<int, int[]> Dict = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
private static int hitcount = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Example data
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    Dict.Add(1, new int[] { 2, 3, 4 });
    Dict.Add(2, new int[] { 3, 6 });
    Dict.Add(3, new int[] { 5, 6 });
    Dict.Add(4, new int[] { 2, 3 });
    Dict.Add(5, new int[] { 6 });
    Dict.Add(6, new int[] { });

    var links = GetAllLinks(1);

    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(link.ToString());
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("MS:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " - " + hitcount);
    Console.ReadKey();
}


private static List<int> GetLinksFromKey(int key)
{
    //This usually takes avg 800ms so sleep here
    //This is the BottleNeck, the more often its called longer it will take
    Thread.Sleep(800);
    hitcount++;
    return Dict[key].ToList();
}

private static List<int> GetAllLinks(int key)
{
    var alreadyDone = new HashSet<int>();
    var workingOn = new HashSet<int>();

    var pages = new List<int>();

    RecursiveGetAllLinks(pages, alreadyDone, workingOn, key);

    return pages;
}

private static void RecursiveGetAllLinks(List<int> pages, HashSet<int> alreadyDone, HashSet<int> workingOn, int key)
{
    if (!workingOn.Add(key))
    {
        throw new Exception("Cyclic recursion for " + key);
    }

    var links = GetLinksFromKey(key);

    foreach (int link in links)
    {
        if (alreadyDone.Contains(link))
        {
            continue;
        }

        RecursiveGetAllLinks(pages, alreadyDone, workingOn, link);
    }

    alreadyDone.Add(key);
    pages.Add(key);

    workingOn.Remove(key);
}
```

I have two `HashSet<>`: one for the pages I've already completely parsed (with all their links) and one for the pages that I'm parsing (to check against recursion). At this time I'm using an `Exception()` in case of recursion, but it should be possible to `return false` everywhere and check everywhere against this `false` value in case of recursion.

This piece of code is `O(N)` in respect to calls to `GetLinksFromKey()`, so if there are a total of 6 pages, it should do the loading exactly N times.

Note that this code is recursive... Recursion is a two edged sword... Normally there shouldn't be problems of `StackOverflowException` on something like this (you won't have 10000 deep links)

Comment: I indeed won't have that many links. I will go and try to implement this, if it works like expected I will accept your anwer. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The full operation went from 38950ms to 14730ms. Thank you very much!